# Show distance from plane to origin is $\leq$ 1

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have been given the surface $x^2-y^2+z^2=1$, and I'm supposed to show that the distance between any tangent plane to the surface is $\leq 1$

So far I've been able to show that the equations of the tangent planes to the surface is $x_0x-y_0y+z_0z=1$ and the distance formula is $\frac{1}{x_0^2+y_0^2+z_0^2}$, but I can't prove it's less or equal to 1...

Comment: What is $x_0,y_0,z_0$?

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla I think he means the tangent plane at point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$

Comment: I don't get it how could the distance be that if $(x,y,z)_0$ is on the plane.

Comment: The question doesn't make much sense because tangents touch the surface, so they are distance $0$ away?

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla I think he means take any two tangents planes $P_1,P_2$, then the distance between these two is less than $1$ namely $\text{dist}(P_1,P_2)\leq 1$

Comment: $x_0^2+y_0^2+z_0^2\ge  x_0^2-y_0^2+z_0^2=1$. So $\frac{1}{x_0^2+y_0^2+z_0^2}\le 1$.

Answer (score 0):

As you found, the distance from origin to the tangent plane at $M(x_0,y_0,z_0) $ is given by

$$d (O,P)=\frac {1}{x_0^2+y_0^2+z_0^2} $$

but the point $M $ is supposed lying in the surface, thus
$$x_0^2-y_0^2+z_0^2=1$$
the distance becomes

$$d (O,P)=\frac {1}{2y_0^2+1} $$ which is clearly $\le 1$.